# showing $T^n = \mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$, $n$ dimensional torus is complete

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

I want to prove $n$ dimensional torus $T^n = \mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$ is complete?  [I know torus is compact since torus is a compact metric space, so from "Every compact metric space is complete" $T^n$ is complete.]

Can one prove this without using the compactness of $T^n$?

---

First I know this $n$ dimensional torus is a metric space, i.e.,

\begin{align}
  d(x+\Bbb Z^n, y+\Bbb Z^n) = \inf\{ \|v-w\| : v \in x+\Bbb Z^n \textrm{ and } w\in y + \Bbb Z^n\} 
\end{align}

and metric space is called complete if every Cauchy sequence has a limit.

Also I know $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a complete space. But I am not sure how its quotient space is complete.

Comment: If you want to prove it from scratch, given a Cauchy sequence on the torus, show that there exists a lift of this Cauchy sequence in the universal cover, namely $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is also Cauchy, use that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, and then deduce that the original Cauchy sequence has a limit. I can help with details if you want.

Comment: @Malkoun, Hello! Can you explain more about "given a Cauchy sequence on the torus, show that there exists a lift of this Cauchy sequence in the universal cover"? I understand your comment as : Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, cauchy sequence converges in the universal cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence it converges on $T^n$. But I am not familiar with why completness of universal cover implies completness of torus.

Comment: @phy_math: Completeness of a metric space means that every Cauchy sequence in that metric space converges. So: you start with a Cauchy sequence in $T^n$, lift it above to $\Bbb R^n$, show that it converges there, show that the projection down below to $T^n$ gives a limit of the original sequence. Thus, you've shown that all Cauchy sequences in $T^n$ have a limit in $T^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_m) \subset \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ be a Cauchy sequence. Let $(y_m) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a lift of $(x_m)$. Note that we have some freedom in defining each $y_m$. Indeed,

$$y'_m = y_m + a_m$$

where $a_m \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ defines another lift $(y'_m)$ of $(x_m)$. I claim that one may choose $(y_m)$ such that it is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Indeed, since $(x_m)$ is Cauchy, then, taking $\epsilon = 1/4$, there is an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ l, m \geq M \implies d(x_l, x_m) < \frac{1}{4}$$.

In particular,

$$ \forall m \geq M, d(x_m, x_M) < \frac{1}{4}. $$

Let $y_M \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be any lift of $x_M$. Then for $m > M$, let $y_m$ be the unique lift of $x_m$ such that $d(y_m, y_M) < 1/4$. We have some freedom in defining the beginning of the sequence $(y_m)$, namely for $m < M$, but of course, this does not affect convergence, nor being Cauchy.

I claim that $(y_m)$, thus constructed, is Cauchy. Indeed, the tail of $(y_m)$, for $m \geq M$, is isometric to the tail of $(x_m)$, for $m \geq M$, so that $(y_m)$ is also Cauchy, albeit in $\mathbb{R}^n$, rather than the $n$-torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$. But $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, so $(y_m)$ converges to, say, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

By continuity of the projection map
$$ p: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n $$
since $(y_m)$ converges to $y$, it follows that $(p(y_m) = x_m)$ converges to $p(y)$.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^n / T^n$ is right? Is that should be $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: @phy_math, yes you are right. I made the same typo 3 times (I am used to quotienting out by a torus). I fixed it now.